# How to compute new camera extrinsics after coordinates system transformation?

Tags: opencv, camera-calibration, coordinate-transformation

I am trying to compute new camera extrinsics after coordinates tranformation. Say, the old extrinsics(rotation and transformation) are R0, T0. I first rotate the coordinates system α along X-axis, then β along Y-axis, and then γ along Z-axis, αβγ are in radian and rotation follows the right hand rule. Also I translate the coordinates system by Tt.

Let's denote:

```
Rx = {1, 0, 0; 
      0, cosα, -sinα;
      0, sinα, cosα}

Ry = {cosβ, 0, sinβ; 
      0, 1, 0;
      -sinβ, 0, cosβ}

Rz = {cosγ, -sinγ, 0; 
      0, 1, 0;
      sinγ, cosγ, 1}
```

So after this transformation, will the new extrinsics become R = R0* Rx* Ry* Rz, and T = T0+Tt?

Also I wonder what the new coordinates of a given 3D point will be like. Say, the old 3D coordinates is P0 (3X1), will its new coordinates become Rx* Ry* Rz* P0 - Tt?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I have got the answer after lots of tests.
After the transformation, the new extrinsics will be:

R = R0 * Rx^(-1) * Ry^(-1) * Rz^(-1); //-1 is the inverse or the transpose (they are equal)

T = Rz * Ry * Rx * T0 + Tt;

//New coordinates:
P = Rz * Ry * Rx * P0 + Tt;

**NB.** It's easy to make mistakes for T. T is not T0 + Tt